# how to implement asynchronous get in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

what should I write in the script to make javascript asynchronously implement firstly ajax method GET and then another simple function(in the order of my script)?

because here while debugging I see that getCategories() is implemented before WriteCategories(categories)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/ListingAPI/GetCategoriesById?id=1',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function WriteCategories(categories) {
        // ...
    }
});
var test = getCategories();
```

Comment: As you've already seen in one answer, it is asynch.  Also beware: an ajax call may interrupt a previous one, so you never receive the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you want synchronous execution,

you need to add `async: false` in ajax request, (But be aware of this it will freeze your UI until your request completes, actually it is not recommended)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/ListingAPI/GetCategoriesById?id=1',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function WriteCategories(categories) {
        // ...
    }
});
var test = getCategories();
```

or either you can call your function on ajax success callback,

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/ListingAPI/GetCategoriesById?id=1',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function WriteCategories(categories) {
            var test = getCategories();
    }
});
```

For your knowledge,  You can pass your query string params in `data` option in ajax rather than query string itself,

```
var queryStringData = {id : 1}
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/ListingAPI/GetCategoriesById',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: queryStringData,
    success: function WriteCategories(categories) {
            var test = getCategories();
    }
});
```

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated and should not be used, also its just bad example

Comment: @Mevia agreed, but as OP needs synchronous execution,

Comment: if you need synchronous ajax - it means that architecture of your application is badly designed. OP is clearly unexperienced and i don't believe that teaching him/her bad practices is right thing to do. It should be pointed out that app should be redesigned instead of encourage to use deprecated functionality

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/ListingAPI/GetCategoriesById?id=1',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function WriteCategories(categories) {
        var test = getCategories();
    }
});
```

You can call this function after ajax success. By this way AJAX get will be executed first.